# Magento : create ajax dropdown populated with labels of 3 product's attributes.

Tags: magento, drop-down-menu, product

Greetings,

I'm, unluckily in need of having this :

```
    Product has (lets say) 6 attributes with "Yes/No" values.
    I need a dropdown on that product's page that will populate with attributes with "yes" value.

    attributes are :bundle1,bundle2....,bundle6.
    When selection is made - I need to know whats have been selected to pass that to php on that page.
```

I have no idea what preexists in Magento (in terms of Ajax snippets) that could be used for this, searching for solution...

I used additional request.js and pulled attributes from a newly created table in DB (manually, for 1 product, just for test) and it works.
 But, thats not idea, I dont want to do it manually everytime.

Syntax is killling me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be helpful at all...  But I just recently created a module that taps into Magento's ajax autopopulate functionality.  What this module does is does an autopopulate of all the manufacturers, depending on the string you are typing in.  I know this isn't directly what you are wanting to do, but this may help you get started, at least with the ajax:

/app/etc/modules/Ash_Manufacturers.xml
http://pastie.org/841014

/app/code/local/Ash/Manufacturers/etc/config.xml
http://pastie.org/841017

/app/code/local/Ash/Manufacturers/controllers/IndexController.php
http://pastie.org/841018

/app/code/local/Ash/Manufacturers/Block/Manufacturers.php
http://pastie.org/841020

Look at rows 79-92 on this one:
/app/design/frontend/default/ash/template/catalog/layer/filter.phtml : http://pastie.org/841027